# Mouse Event to move frame not working

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse

I have the following code:

```
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        frame.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
    }
});
```

`panel` is a `JPanel`, and all imports have been included. Now, when I drag the `panel`, the `frame` doesn't move a tiny bit. Why is this, and how should I go about fixing it?

***EDIT***: `frame` is undecorated.
***EDIT***: `mouseDragged` isn't getting triggered - that's the problem to fix!
***EDIT***: CODE!!!!!

```
package user_interface;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.add(new JPanel());
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(0));
        panel.setToolTipText("Drag to move frame");
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Test.this.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
        this.add(panel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.add(new JPanel());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setSize(750, 500);
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // 3
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: And for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869877/how-to-remove-window-box-from-any-java-gui/16869893#16869893) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836201/jframe-wrong-location-with-ubuntu-unity/30836537#30836537)

Comment: [_et al._](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20ComponentMover)

Comment: I've noticed that the mousedragged isn't even getting triggered.

Comment: ***"EDIT:** frame is undecorated."*  O...K.  How is the user supposed to know that a borderless frame ***can*** be dragged?  It is counterintuitive.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Although it doesn't work on a bordered frame either (don't ask why I'm not just using the window border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MouseMotionListener for that purpose.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(new Color(0));
panel.setToolTipText("Drag to move frame");

panel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       super.mouseDragged(e);
       Test.this.setLocation(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen());
       System.out.println(e);
    }
});

this.setContentPane(panel);
```

Comment: Thanks! I must've just made an error in the method call!